# What is the Best Practice for textbox validation based on select box value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have one select box based on the select box value i need to check text box mandatory or not. I have done with jQuery validation but my question is  I got values from database for the select box i keep the name as value and id as key for select box. I have select box like

```
<select name="selectBox1" class="default textbox-select" tabindex="2">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="1">A</option>
 <option value="2">B</option>
 <option value="3">C</option>
 </select>



<input type="text" name="email" class="textbox-cont-regular"/>
```

if i choose the value B means only the email text box should be mandatory.I have write validation based on the hard code value 2. Is it best practice or any ideas to improve my self. because any one change the values in db means my validation will not work? or i shall i write validation based on the text("B"). Which is a best practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To future proof you can have a database structure like this.

```
Value Text IsMandatory
----------------------
1     A    false     
2     B    true
3     C    false
```

Then using your server side markup code generation (php/asp.net etc) you can generate some html like this

```
<select id="selectBox1" name="selectBox1">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="1">A</option>
 <option value="2" data-mandatory="true">B</option>
 <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

then you can specify your rule like

```
rules : {
 email : {
  required: "#selectBox1 option[data-mandatory]:selected"
 }
}
```

With this structure you can change the id values or the text in the database without having to touch your markup or validation code.  You can also change the number of values that make the text box mandatory, or make them all optional etc.

[fiddle to demonstrate this approach here](http://jsfiddle.net/baMVw/)

Answer (score 1):

Choose the criteria for your validation which is not going to change, so that you wont have problems in the future. So in this case, i would suggest you go with the text option if thats not going to change